# Number of subsets of a set with cardinality $k$ containing a specific element

Tags: combinatorics, set-theory, binomial-coefficients

Let $M$ be a fixed set with $m$ elements and $i \in M$ is fixed. How many subsets $K$ of $M$ with exactly $k$ elements are there such that $i \in K$?

My reasoning is the following. If we take $\tilde{M} = M\setminus\{i\}$, then the question reduces to the number of subsets of $\tilde{M}$ with $k-1$ elements, so the answer for the problem is $\binom{m-1}{k-1}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Yes, this is correct.